# To view a Text file Activity chooser doesn't not open in Gallexy NOTE 2 but opens in HTC one V

Tags: android-intent, android-activity, permission-denied

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT);
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
intent.setDataAndType(uri, "text/plain");
startActivity(intent);
```

Here is my Log..

Problem:

> 03-31 11:12:50.856: E/AndroidRuntime(1879):
>   java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent {
>   act=android.intent.action.EDIT
>   dat=file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.myapp/files/Tttttttt.txt
>   typ=text/plain cmp=com.dropbox.android/.activity.TextEditActivity }
>   from ProcessRecord{451f6e18 1879:com.megaebin/u0a10197} (pid=1879,
>   uid=10197) not exported from uid 10038

Comment: > .. not exported..

means in your manifest you should add the "android:exported" attribute to your activity. The default value could depend on the Android version or the device manufacturer. There should be a test in the CTS for this.